# Can't move main picture higher in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project on my course and I am finding it difficult to figure out how to move higher the main picture of the page since it moves the whole section.

What I know and what I tried is this : I did create a separate div class on the picture, as well as putting it on a different section but unfortunately it would move the whole section with the title and paragraph higher at the same time.

```
<section class="block">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
          <h5 class="block--text__hello">Hello, I am</h5>
          <h1 class="block--main__title">CALEB NYONG</h1>
          <h2 class="block--main__subtitle">UI/UX & Product Designer</h2>
          <p class="block--main__content">I’m a top online marketer and branding expert, I started my career
            by lauching the popular metaverse design, in just a few short
            years, I built the brand to millions of social media followers and websites visitors.</p>
          <div class="links">
            <div>
                <button type="button">Hire Me</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h5 class="block--title__bold">Download CV</h5>
            </div>
            <div>
                <svg class="block--vector" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 22 21" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M1 15.5L1.621 17.985C1.72915 18.4177 1.97882 18.8018 2.33033 19.0763C2.68184 19.3508 3.11501 19.4999 3.561 19.5H18.439C18.885 19.4999 19.3182 19.3508 19.6697 19.0763C20.0212 18.8018 20.2708 18.4177 20.379 17.985L21 15.5M11 13.5V1.5V13.5ZM11 13.5L7 9.5L11 13.5ZM11 13.5L15 9.5L11 13.5Z" stroke="#FCC028" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                </svg>                            
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="main--picture">
        <img src="./img/portrait-smiling-handsome-man-eyeglasses_171337-4853 1.png" alt="">
     </div>
</section>
```

Above is the code that contains the picture and the whole section that contains all the other parts. I need the code in #css

If you need any other information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand clearly what you want to ask. Where do you want to show the picture?

Comment: Can you post a doodle of what you want?

Comment: Hi there. If I understood correctly, you want us to write a css code for you to place portrait above other elements?

Comment: @PeterJames yes, I am sorry for the confusion. I want the code to remain the same just move the picture higher.

Comment: @PeterJames I need to move the main picture higher, when I code on CSS about the margin of the picture it won't move only the main picture but as well the "Hello I am" and anything below it...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to set an image as background.
Then you can do something like this:

```
.block {
   background-image: url("./img/portrait-smiling-handsome-man-eyeglasses_171337-4853 1.png");
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/adelathomaj/pen/XWEqyNz

Comment: Here is the code in html and CSS, I have this figma file as a homework : https://www.figma.com/file/JCFmTJqroixiz5FfoYVcKe/Portfolio-Website-For-Designers-(Community)?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: On figma, the main picture, which is this smiling guy, is placed a bit higher than it is currently. When I try to move it higher by adding it in a separate div it also moves higher the paragraph and the whole section I pasted above.